# How to put a certain text or string after the first occurrence of loop in xsl?

Tags: xslt

I just need to put "(Constituent Corporation)" after the first occurrence of the absorbed company. Or in other words, put that string on the 2nd absorbedComapny occurrence and so on except the 1st. Thank you in advance!

```
      <xsl:for-each select="absorbedCompanies/absorbedCompany">
      <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center" space-after.optimum="0pt"> <xsl:value-of select="absorbedCompanyName"/>&#xA0;<xsl:value-of select="absorbedSuffix"/>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center" space-after.optimum="1pt"> <xsl:value-of select="absorbedDoingBusiness"/>
      </fo:block> 
      <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center" space-after.optimum="0pt"> 
      </fo:block> 
       <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center"  space-after.optimum="20pt">( Constituent Corporations )
    </fo:block>



                     <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()-1">
                          <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center" space-after.optimum="10pt">and
                          </fo:block>   
                    </xsl:if>
                     <xsl:if test="position() = last()-1"> 
                        <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center" space-after.optimum="10pt">and
                        </fo:block>   
                    </xsl:if>
                     <xsl:if test="position() = last()"></xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"position() > 1" should work for you.

```
<xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
    <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center" space-after.optimum="20pt">( Constituent Corporations ) </fo:block>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: it worked, i never thought of that. Sorry im new with xslt. Thank you very much sir